# Executing shell command in background from ruby with proper argument escaping

Tags: ruby, shell, background, escaping

I have to run a command in the background but I want to have proper escaping for its parameter.

```
system("rake send_mails subject='#{params[:subject]}' 2> /dev/null 1> /dev/null &");
```

If I write `system("rake", "send_mails", params[:subject])` then I don't have "place" for redirections and the `&` sign. If I don't I do not have escaping for the `subject` parameter.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I am not sure, but did you try to nest `system` calls? For example: `system(system("rake", "send_mails", params[:subject]), "/dev/null 1> /dev/null &")`

Comment: The inner `system()` call is executed then the outer `system()` fails without executing anything: `TypeError: can't convert true into String`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9, try [Process.spawn](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Process.html#M002230):

```
# Spawn a new process and run the rake command
pid = Process.spawn({"subject" => params[:subject]},
                    "rake", "send_mails",
                    :out => 'dev/null', :err => 'dev/null')

# Detach the spawned process
Process.detach pid
```

Comment: The point would be not to wait at all. We have to move on to processing the next web query - as I failed to mention it. But that's the point in redirecting the output to `/dev/null` and running with `&` - to reach complete detachment.

Comment: Then use Process.detach after you've spawned the new process. I will edit my answer to include this.

Comment: Adding that `Process.fork do ... end` is available and close-to-perfect in 1.8.7.

Comment: But I am still hungry for a function like PHP's `escapeshellarg()`.

Comment: I know it has been a while, but there is Shellwords: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949008/executing-shell-command-in-background-from-ruby-with-proper-argument-escaping

Comment: @radiospiel Your link points to this very page. Maybe some copy-paste mistake?

Comment: @Notinlist my bad, the correct link would probably be something line http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html