# How to avoid blocked by call system call in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails
I have a system call in my action of controller.

```
%x [ run_my_script ]
```

which will run for many hours...
I found once i call the system call ,i can not open the same page again,
because i guess the rails was busying in waiting for the return of the sys call.

if i want to execute the page in parrallel
how should i do???
using thread?
I have tried sidekiq , it will consuming lots lots of memory ! 
is there any ideas...
thanks you all in advance.

Comment: With a delayed_job ? https://rubygems.org/gems/delayed_job

Comment: take a look at the related question about [Process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949008/executing-shell-command-in-background-from-ruby-with-proper-argument-escaping)

Answer (score 1):

You can use system command with & at the end to run it in background.. not sure if you can use with %x[]

```
system "run_my_script &"
```